# How to Join My Invoice and Invoice Product table with sql query..?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table invoice and invoice product table, i want to join my two table with respect to each invoice id.

I have tried to write sql query but it is wrong.

```
SELECT invoice.invoice_id, invoice_product.product_name
FROM invoice, invoice_product
WHERE invoice.invoice_id = invoice_product.invoices_id
```

I want to show my actually result like this.

```
Invoice_id | Invoice_name | Product_name                | Created Date
========== |============= |=============================|==============
   1       |    Test 1    |   Product1 ,product 2       | 2019-05-02
   2       |    Test 2    |    New Product ,New Product | 2019-05-02
```

`invoice` table:

[image]

`invoice_product` table:

[image]

Comment: I am using mysql database with php.

Comment: group_concat...

Comment: please give me a sample code if possible.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `group_concat()`

```
SELECT invoice.invoice_id, group_concat(invoice_product.product_name)
FROM invoice join  invoice_product
on invoice.invoice_id = invoice_product.invoices_id
group by invoice.invoice_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `GROUP_CONCAT` to get the list of products like that, grouping by invoice number. This will work:

```
SELECT i.invoice_id, i.invoice_name, GROUP_CONCAT(ip.product_name) AS products, i.created_at
FROM invoice i
JOIN invoice_product ip ON i.invoice_id = ip.invoices_id
GROUP BY i.invoice_id
```

Output:

```
invoice_id  invoice_name    products                        created_at
1           Test 1          Product 1,Product 2             2019-05-02 00:00:00
2           Test 2          Product New,Product New New     2019-05-02 00:00:00
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=7c4a6bc4c9fb517e3773e9fac111ee95)

Note that implicit `JOIN` syntax using comma has been deprecated for a while, it is better to write explicit `JOIN`s instead.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid jointure with your actual syntax, this is too old.
I do not recommand to have non-atomic values but the `GROUP_CONCAT` function is doing the work for you.

```
SELECT invoice.invoice_id, GROUP_CONCAT(IP.product_name), I.created_at
FROM invoice AS I
JOIN invoice_product AS IP
    ON I.invoice_id = IP.invoices_id
GROUP BY IP.invoices_id
```